# Create a derived field for a custom Drupal 7 Entity for use with Views

Tags: views, entities

I've created a really simple entity; basically it's for news headlines - that is, links to articles on other sites. (Using nodes would have been overkill). I've used the entity module to take care of the heavy-lifting, and everything's working nicely.

Thus, my entity has a `title` and a `URL` field.

This entity then needs a "rendered link" field - the title, linked to the URL. Essentially just a call to `l()` - that's the easy part. I've got this working in the most part by adding a new "derived" field to the entity, by overriding the entity controller's `buildContent` method.

What I now want to do is make this available as a field in my Views. All my other fields are available, and whilst I know how to override a views handler and use `hook_views_data_alter` for a given field which maps to a pre-existing schema column, e.g.:

`/**
 * Implements hook_views_data_alter(). 
 */
function mymodule_views_data_alter(&$data) 
   $data['table']['column']['field']['handler'] = 'my_custom_view_handler_field';
}`

...what I can't work out is how to create a "derived field" such as this, where there's no one-to-one mapping with a schema field.

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't have time to write a full example but basically you add a field as normal via `hook_views_data()`, give it a custom field handler, and in that field handler override `query()` and `additional_fields()` in a way similar to the code at the top [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/507618). Then override `render()` to produce the markup

Comment: Actually, have a look [here](http://knackforge.com/blog/selvam/drupal-7-exposing-pseudo-field-view-custom-table) at the use of the "real field" property - that might be what you're looking for

Comment: Between them, those two links gave me everything I needed to get it working - many thanks, @Clive!